# Need Help finding out howto use Twitter's @anywhere isFollowing/isFollowedBy methods

Tags: javascript, api, twitter, sizzle, twitter-anywhere

I am trying to check via the Twitter Javascript Api (see [here](http://platform.twitter.com/js-api.html)) if a logged in user is following me on twitter. If not, i will display a followbutton.
Right now i can't seem to find out how the command isFollowing/isFollowedBy works (see doc).

Code so far:

```
twttr.anywhere( function (T) {
    if(T.User.find('mashable').isFollowing){
        alert("Mashable is following current logged in User");
    }
);
```

Have also tried `.isFollowing()`, `.isFollowing('username')`, `.isFollowing().find('username')` and many many more alternatives. Nothing works so far. Can someone help me find out how to properly use this Method?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not experienced with the API but it seems

```
T.User.find('mashable').isFollowing()
```

would be right.

Adding a curly brace might help though, you're missing one to end the function definition:

```
twttr.anywhere( function (T) {
    if(T.User.find('mashable').isFollowing()){
        alert("Mashable is following current logged in User");
    }
});
```